# How do I check the user permission for a folder using java

Tags: java, filesystems

I want check whether a logged in user has permissions like "write" or "Read and Execute" for a folder that the user is using as destination for an installation.

Basically I am using the InstallAnyWhere to prepare the installer. I want the installer to check the given destination has the above permissions for the loggedin user or not, if the user does not have these permission the installer should throw a warning message.

I need this to be done using java. Is there a way to check this using java?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
File dir = new File("/path/to/dir");
dir.canRead();
dir.canWrite();
...
```

Comment: Mhm... i think this will check the permissions for the user which started the jvm process aint it?

Comment: yes, but I assume that will be the case - you start the installer as yourself. Anyway, you can't check for other users.

Comment: Yes you're right i missed the point, that this is for installation purposes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java 7 there is a new way to get file attributes. I am assuming that you are on Unix based OS (since you are talking about write and execute permissions on a directory).

The method you can use is [Files.getAttribute(Path, String, LinkOption...)](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/nio/javadoc/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAttributes%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.lang.Class,%20java.nio.file.LinkOption...%29). In your case it should return [PosixFileAttributeView](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/nio/javadoc/index.html?java/nio/file/attribute/PosixFileAttributeView.html).

You can find more details at the [Managing Metadata](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileAttr.html) section of the Java NIO tutorial.